# Value Object as Invalid Object in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1, value-objects

I have been using value object in asp.net core 2.0 project, which was running properly on that project.

I updated the project to 2.1 and it is giving me an error as

`Invalid object name 'EntityAdress'.`

Entity:

```
public class Company : AuditableEntity<long>
{
    public int SalesRepId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public EntityAdress Addresses { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class EntityAdress : ValueObject
{
    private EntityAdress() { }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues()
    {
        yield return Address;
        yield return City;
        yield return State;
        yield return Zip;
    }
}
```

The implementation for ValueObject is exact same from the [Link for the eshopContainer examples of value objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects)

The Package i am using for the projects which contains the `DbContext`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">


  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.6</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.EntityFramework" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();
    modelBuilder.OnDeleteCascading();

    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CompanyEntityTypeConfiguraton());

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

}
```

CompanyEntityTypeConfiguraton:

```
public class CompanyEntityTypeConfiguraton : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> orderConfiguration)
    {
        orderConfiguration.OwnsOne(p => p.Addresses, cb =>
        {
            cb.Property(p => p.City).HasColumnName("City");
            cb.Property(p => p.Address).HasColumnName("Address");
            cb.Property(p => p.State).HasColumnName("State");
            cb.Property(p => p.Zip).HasColumnName("Zip");
        });

    }
}
```

OnDeleteCascading and RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (IMutableEntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            entity.Relational().TableName = entity.DisplayName();
        }
    }
    public static void OnDeleteCascading(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }
    }

}
```

What could be the reason for the problems? Is it the problem with the Entity Framework version or something missing on the implementations?

Comment: There are definitely some changes related to owned types in 2.1. The first thing you should do is to create new migration - if it is not empty, then something is causing EF Core mapping change. For instance, the first two modelBuilder calls are suspicious (especially the second) - they are non standard EF Core methods and are called before the `EntityAdress` is identified as owned entity. Can you post the source code of the `OnDeleteCascading` method?

Comment: @IvanStoev i have added the code for `OnDeleteCascading`. I have updated after the migration is created.

Comment: Good. Actually I was suspecting the other method, but luckily you have included it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are always some changes in the implementation between EF Core versions. Some could be a bug fixes, which can cause the old code running differently.

The problem is this code:

```
public static void RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (IMutableEntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        entity.Relational().TableName = entity.DisplayName();
    }
}
```

First, you should exclude owned types (remember owned types are still entities in EF Core, hence are included in `GetEntityTypes()`):

```
modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(t => !t.IsOwned())
```

otherwise you are changing the EF Core default behavior of not creating separate table for the owned entity (the so called table splitting) to actually create a separate table, hence the exception you are getting when EF Core builds SQL query joining to the table that does not exist.

Second, you should call that code **after** all fluent configuration, because at the beginning the owned entities (in case are not marked with `[Owned]` attribute) are not identified as such yet - it happens only after `OwnsOne` calls.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CompanyEntityTypeConfiguraton());

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();
    modelBuilder.OnDeleteCascading();
}
```