# ef core 2 splits sql tables for owned type - don't want this

Tags: ef-core-2.2

this documentation : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

... sais that : 
"When using relational databases, by convention reference owned types are mapped to the same table as the owner."

But in my case it doesn't - the owned type is stored in a separate table !

This is my case:

```
public class OwnerClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public OwnedClass OwnedClass { get; set; }
    }

    [Owned]
    public class OwnedClass
    {
        public string FirstProperty { get; set; }
        public int SecondProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

and it produces this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Myapp.Models.OwnerClass", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("OwnerClass");
                });



modelBuilder.Entity("Myapp.Models.OwnerClass", b =>
                {
                    b.OwnsOne("Myapp.Models.OwnedClass", "OwnedClass", b1 =>
                        {
                            b1.Property<int>("OwnerClassId");

                            b1.Property<string>("FirstProperty");

                            b1.Property<int>("SecondProperty");

                            b1.HasKey("OwnerClassId");

                            b1.ToTable("OwnedClass");

                            b1.HasOne("Myapp.Models.OwnerClass")
                                .WithOne("OwnedClass")
                                .HasForeignKey("Myapp.Models.OwnedClass", "OwnerClassId")
                                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                        });
                });
```

my configuration:

netcoreapp2.2

and

(for storage in mysql)

Thanks a lot for any ideas and help !

Best regards, 
Fabianus

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a code which applies "custom naming convention" like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801640/value-object-as-invalid-object-in-asp-net-core-2-1/53802310#53802310?

Comment: @IvanStoev - thanks so much, you're right !